# how add new item to listview in fragment B from click button on fragment A with Viewpager

Tags: listview

I have a edittext and a button in Fragment SpeechToText (ID in Viewpager is 2). When i click button, it will send this edittext to fragment MyListWord (ID in Viewpager is 0) ( I use interface ). (It mean send data from tab 3 to tab 1 in Tablayout)

I have a listview in Fragment MyListWord. How I add this text to this listview?

My code:

Fragment SpeechtoText:

```
private SendData mSendata;

public interface SendData {
    public void SendDataMainActivity(String contentWord);
}


@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        this.mSendata = (SendData) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + e.toString());
    }
}
```

onButtonclickListener:

```
String contentWord = edittext.getText();
mSendata.SendDataMainActivity(contentWord);
```

MainActivity implements SpeechToText.SendData

```
public void SendDataMainActivity(String contentWord)
{
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    MyListWord myListWord = (MyListWord)manager.findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + pager.getId() + ":" + 0);
    myListWord.Getdata(contentWord);
}
```

And in Fragment MyListWord:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_list_word, container, false);

    lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvMylistword);

    ArrayList<String> Word = new ArrayList<String>();

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(
            getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            Word 
    );
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}

 public void Getdata(ContentWord contentWord)
{
    if(contentWord.getWordContent().length()!=0)
    {
       ////I want add this contentWord to listview .....
    }
}
```

In Getdata function, how i add this word to listview, I have tried notifyDatasetChanged() in Getdata but not work.

Thank all.

Answer (score 0):

Sr for my stupid Question :D

Because I send data from Tab 3 to tab 1, so it error.

I edit Fragment MyListWord to Tab 2, and Fragment SpeechToText to tab 3, it success

Here my code in Getdata

```
 public void Getdata(ContentWord contentWord)
{
    if(contentWord.getWordContent().length()!=0)
    {
        ArrayList<ContentWord> List_contentWords = new ArrayList<ContentWord>();
        List_contentWords = adaptor.getListData();
        List_contentWords.add(new ContentWord("ABCD","Noud",0));
        adaptor.setListData(List_contentWords);
        adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```